# Doubt regarding Strtok in PHP

Tags: php, strtok

```
<?php
    $string = "sandesh commented on institue international institute of technology";
    /* Use tab and newline as tokenizing characters as well  */
    $tok = strtok($string, " \n\t");
    echo $tok
    ?>
```

The above code gives me output sandesh.

But if I want the output "commented on institute international institute of technology", then how should I modify the above code.

Thanks and Regards
Sandesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$string = "sandesh commented on institue international institute of technology";
echo substr($string,strpos($string," ")+1);
```

documentation

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

**Edit**

> i actually need the string after the fourth token

```
<?php
$string = "sandesh commented on institue international institute of technology";
$str_array = explode(" ",$string);
$str_array = slice($str_array,4);
echo implode(" ",$str_array);
```

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php

Comment: hi, here i actually need the string after the fourth token , for that i can repeat this for 4 times , is there any way directly i can get the string after fourth token , without putting into loop.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're tokenizing based on space, `strtok` gives you the first word. The next time you call strtok, you'll get the second word, etc. There is no way, given the string that you have and the token that you supply, to get the rest of the string as a single token.

Comment: thanks..can i know the reason , i guess it will remember the pointer.

Comment: Yes; it works exactly like C's strtok. It tokenizes the string you provide, and you loop over it, performing whatever actions.

Answer (score 1):

> *is there any way directly i can get the string after fourth token ,
>   without putting into loop.*

This will get the string after the fourth space in one pass.

```
<?php
$string = "sandesh commented on institue international institute of technology";
preg_match('/(?:.*?\s){4}(.*)/', $string, $m);
$new_string = $m[1];
echo $new_string;
?>
```

Output

> international institute of technology