# substrings in php

Tags: php, substr

Hi I have the following

```
string = "joseph daniel commented on project aadhar"
```

How can I split the above string into 4 parts ie

`"joseph daniel"`, `"commented on"`, `"project"` and  `"aadhar"`

Thanks and regards

Comment: Based on what criteria?  How is the script supposed to detect the user's name?

Comment: You just asked a similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362547/doubt-regarding-strtok-in-php a couple hours ago. You should be clear as to what you actually want to do.

Comment: sub string before the "commented on" is considered to be username. and also here project is actually a resource like it can be a person , project ,event and so..on.

Comment: So the format is [name] commented on [resource] [...]? For instance, in the other question the resource was "institue". What about the string, "commented on"? Does it ever change?

Comment: exactly...[name] commented on [resource][resource name].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming the string, "commented on" never changes, you can use:

```
<?php
$string = "sandesh commented on institue international institute of technology";
preg_match('/(.*) commented on (.*?) (.*)/', $string, $m);
var_dump($m);
?>
```

Result

```
Array(
  0 => 'joseph daniel commented on project aadhar'
  1 => 'joseph daniel'
  2 => 'project'
  3 => 'aadhar'
)
```

or

```
Array(
  0 => 'sandesh commented on institue international institute of technology'
  1 => 'sandesh'
  2 => 'institue'
  3 => 'international institute of technology'
)
```

Note to moderators: This question should probably be merged with [Doubt regarding Strtok in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362547/doubt-regarding-strtok-in-php)

Comment: No problem. You should consider removing your other post.

Answer (score 1):

You can use explode function:

```
explode($delimiter , $string);
```

So, delimiter should be " ", and $string should be "joseph daniel commented on project aadhar".

After applying the function, you get an array with all the words from the sentence.

Preety neat :)

Comment: Please explain upvote ;) This doesn't produce the OP's desired results at all.

Comment: if the structure of the string is always the same (NAME SURNAME commented on project PROJECT), then you know which elements in the array you are looking for (1st, 2nd and 6th).. i hope it helps :)

Comment: Via his comments, there's no information on the structure other than `* commented on *` He has a duplicate question in which the string is `sandesh commented on institue international institute of technology`

Comment: yes `* commented on *` is the right structure :) But somewhat, it is odd that somebody needs to extract this information (author, topic) from a string :)

Comment: I am sorry webbiedave , the actual format is [name] commented on [resource] [resource name]. In the previous post i didnt realise that name can have more than one tokens, as well resource and name of the resource can have multiple tokens ..like
[sandesh nagularapu] commented on [event] [COMAD].

Answer (score 0):

Im sure there is more to your question - for example you have variations of the sentence ? if not this will work :

```
$sentence = "joseph daniel commented on project aadhar";
$first = substr($sentence, 0, 13);
$second = substr($sentence, 14, 12);
$third = substr($sentence, 27, -1);
```

You need to include other examples of the words if you want a better answer

Comment: @above, cant it be done without mentioning the index??
The usual format of the string is name "commented on" some project
I need to separate name ,commented on ,project and its name?

Comment: have a look at indexOf - and put the result of indexOf in the substr line

Answer (score -1):

You're not giving us enough info, but gleaning from your comments it appears you need to extract subject and resource from a string in the format of `* commented on *`. To get you started in the right direction you could do:

```
$str = 'joseph daniel commented on project aadhar';
$matches = array();
preg_match('/^(.*)\s+commented on\s+(.*)$/', $str, $matches);
```

This will produce an array of:

```
Array
(
    [0] => joseph daniel commented on project aadhar
    [1] => joseph daniel
    [2] => project aadhar
)
```

`$matches[1]` will contain the name and you can then explode or use another `preg_match` `$matches[2]` to cherry pick out the resource *type*, e.g., project, event, etc. (you'll need a list of resources types compiled). I don't have enough info on the resource types, e.g., if they can be multiple words, so that's all I can give you.

Comment: Care to explain the downvote? Nothing wrong with this answer.

Comment: Had the same problem with my answer.

Comment: Maybe they're using golf scoring.